# Can slow filter/sort script be optimized to run faster?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This function is at the end of another script with multiple functions that run on a `OnEdit` trigger which all run quickly up to this.  It runs so slowly I have attached it to a button to control when I don't need it going but I would appreciate it if anyone has a solution for more speed.

```
function autoSort() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ServiceAppts");
  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow()-1, ss.getLastColumn());
  var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();

  var column_What = 1;
  var filterCriteria_What = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(['Closed','Free'])
    .build();

  var column_When = 2;
  var filterCriteria_When = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(['Past'])
    .build();

  var column_to_sort = 35;
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column_What, filterCriteria_What)
    .setColumnFilterCriteria(column_When, filterCriteria_When)
    .sort(column_to_sort, true);

  var column_to_sort = 3;
  filter.sort(column_to_sort, true);
```

I have also posted the speeds from Execution Transcript.

```
[19-08-18 23:19:06:545 EDT] FilterCriteriaBuilder.setHiddenValues([[Past]]) [0 seconds]
[19-08-18 23:19:06:545 EDT] FilterCriteriaBuilder.build() [0 seconds]
[19-08-18 23:19:06:775 EDT] Filter.setColumnFilterCriteria([1, FilterCriteria]) [0.229 seconds]
[19-08-18 23:19:07:924 EDT] Filter.setColumnFilterCriteria([2, FilterCriteria]) [1.148 seconds]
[19-08-18 23:19:10:837 EDT] Filter.sort([35, true]) [2.912 seconds]
[19-08-18 23:19:16:315 EDT] Filter.sort([3, true]) [5.477 seconds]
```

Comment: I don't see anything to optimize in this script. 1. You can try recreating the entire filter logic with  pure JavaScript and `setValues()`. 2. You can try  [advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) through [sheets api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#SetBasicFilterRequest). Search [samples here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+setBasicFilter). Advanced apps script is usually faster than basic apps script.

Comment: @TheMaster Ty for the research material!